# How to enable antialiasing while using EffectComposer

Tags: three.js

When using the EffectComposer from three.js it seems that the native antialiasing gets lost. The renderer is set with antialiasing: true; however, the result is full of janky edges.

I tried to reduce the aliasing using the FXAA shader but it just doesn't have the quality that native antialiasing provides.

Can somebody please suggest a solution?

Comment: http://uihacker.blogspot.fr/2013/03/javascript-antialias-post-processing.html

Comment: Can you please make your title more descriptive, and expand on your question so it is clear exactly what you are doing, and what the problem is? (code please) Then explain in your answer what you changed, how it helped, and why it worked. This could be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

When using `THREE.FXAAShader`, it's necessary to configure the `resolution` uniform of the respective shader. This is demonstrated in the [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_fxaa) and done like so:

```
var fxaaPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );

var pixelRatio = renderer.getPixelRatio();
var uniforms = fxaaPass.material.uniforms;

uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.x = 1 / ( window.innerWidth * pixelRatio );
uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.y = 1 / ( window.innerHeight * pixelRatio );
```

You have to execute this code when setup your post-processing and in your `resize` event listener. Otherwise FXAA will break if the user resizes the browser window.

`three.js R102`